# The data set name is missing in the data region 'DataSetName' when adding datatable

Tags: datatable, dataset, reportviewer, rdlc

I am getting the following error when building an rdlc report using MS ReportViewer: The data set name is missing in the data region 'DataSetName'.

Basically in my dataset I have a tableadapter which links to a stored procedure and a datatable, which does not link to the database. The purpose of the datatable is to allow me to hold the users parameters used in the report so they can be displayed in the report. The RDLC works without the datatable, but I get this error when added in.

I have added the datatable to the report through datasources and have been able to add the fields into the RDLC.

The process I am following is as per the link I have found:

http://www.ramto.com/blog/post/Using-RDLC-files-and-Microsoft-Report-Viewer-in-ASPNET.aspx

So, have I missed something here, or is it something else?

Comment: Can you post some screen shot or any code or exact message error code???

Comment: There is no code as I have added the datatable to the dataset using the dataset control - that is to say the .xsd file in visual studio studio. Here is the error message: Error 1 The data set name is missing in the data region ‘DataSetName’. C:\Documents and Settings\prem.fd\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\GameChangerApp\GameChangerApp\UI\Reports\ReportBakeryProgressReport.rdlc GameChangerApp

Comment: As u said there is no link to database. so how the datatable will return any data??

Comment: If you look at the link I attached in my original post - this is what I am following.

Comment: Please dont mind as the way it is explained in the post is half shown only.

Comment: Here's the link again http://www.ramto.com/blog/post/Using-RDLC-files-and-Microsoft-Report-Viewer-in-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: I have checked the link but info shown on the post is incomplete or not in detail you can say...Please follow the way it is in the below answer i pasted

Comment: I have followed the link, but this does not work for me. Let me explain my problem this way. I have in my dataset a table adapter and a datatable. Table Adapter links to a Stored Procedure and returns the results to the screen. Datatable simply shows the parameters that were used to run that report. The tableadapter links to an ObjectDataSource on the report using the wizard from the MS ReportViewer/RDLC. In my codebehind on the page I pass in my parameters to the ObjectDataSource. The Report works great with the datatable, but I get the error when trying to use the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

The way its explained on the link attached is little blurry to catch if yoy are a newbie, Follow this code project link everything explained in detail and code is attached to test locally.

[Bind RDLC to report viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31862/Dynamic-Binding-Of-RDLC-To-ReportViewer)

Comment: See my comment above. No luck. It is complaining about this on the RDLC no in any code